# Rails fields_for causing model instance to appear in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is really strange, but when I use a fields_for helper in order to give users the ability to submit multiple instances of my model, the view displays the instance data on the page like so:

[image: rails issue]

Embiggened: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Omjt0.png

The code I have which generates the form is like so:

```
<%= form_for :metric_request, url: '/metric_request', :html => {:multipart => true} do |metric_request| %>

<%= @metric_requests.each do |m| %>

<%= metric_request.fields_for m, index: m.id do |f| %>
```

It works fine in generating multiple copies of my form, but whenever it's included, the view page spits out the model as in the image above. What gives? When I remove the `fields_for` helper, the output model instance text disappears... ?!

Edit: as pointed out by Joel Brewer, this was caused by my stupid copy/paste fail. Didn't pay attention and included the <%= instead of <%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<% @metric_requests.each do |m| %>
```

instead of:

```
<%= @metric_requests.each do |m| %>
```

Comment: gd it, it's always the simple things >.< beware copy/pasting! :)